# Rails fill in two form fields with one dropdown option

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are three models involved in this problem.
Users can create templates, which have title and content attributes. When creating a posting, users can select the template from a dropdown.

I would like to create a form for postings, in which users can select a template's title from a dropdown list, and automatically use that template's attributes for both the posting's content and title in the form.
So far I have managed to create a dropdown for a user's templates, but I am struggling to make the content field do what I described.

```
<%= form_for(@cposting) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label "Use a template" %>
        <%= f.collection_select :title, current_user.templates, :title, :title, { prompt: "Choose a template" }, class: "browser-default" %>

    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't understand. Template have title and content. Posting have title, content and template_id. So when you choose a template from the list, the title and content of the posting must mirror the chosen template?

Comment: In other words, do you want the `content` text field to change according to your templates dropdown choice?

Comment: You're going to need to add javascript if you want to dynamically swap out your content field based on drop down decisions.

Comment: Yes that's right @sebkomianos, is it possible to do it with rails, or do I need to use javascript as Kelseydh suggested?

Comment: @sso777 Sorry to disappoint, Kelseydh is right.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javascript to modify the other fields after a selection is made.  A jquery/coffeescript example:

```
$('#field1').on 'change', ->
  $('#field2').val(@value)
  $('#field3').val(@value)
```